# Qt - How do I get a QGraphicsItem's position relative to scene

Tags: c++, qt

I have this constructor for a class that derives from `QGraphicsRectItem`:

```
Tower::Tower(int x, int y, QGraphicsScene *scene) : QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, width, height)
{
    QBrush brush;   // color it
    brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    brush.setColor(START_COLOR);
    this->setBrush(brush);
    this->setAcceptHoverEvents(true);

    scene->addItem(this);   // add to scene
}
```

And I have this code for a `fire` function which should create a bullet at the center of the Rectangle:

```
void Tower::fire()
{
    Bullet *bullet = new Bullet(scenePos().x() + width / 2, scenePos().y() + height / 2, scene());
}
```

This is the code for `Bullet`:

```
Bullet::Bullet(int x, int y, QGraphicsScene *scene) : QGraphicsRectItem(x, y, width, height)
{
    QBrush brush;   // color it
    brush.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    brush.setColor(color);
    this->setBrush(brush);

    scene->addItem(this);
}
```

When the function runs it creates a bullet at the beginning of the scene. 
What can I do to fix this? 
I checked other questions but their answers didn't work for me.

Comment: add Bullet's code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `QGraphicsRectItem` the position is not at the top left corner of the rectangle, but is the default item position (0, 0).

If you want the scene position of the center you can do something like this:

```
QPointF Tower::sceneCenter()
{
    return mapToScene(rect().center());
}
```